# Remap the Control + S button in javascript (or jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been having troubles with the Control + S button, I would like to remap the Control + S button to something else instead of the save page as window.

** I know that its not possible to disable it**
I want the functionality like what https://www.hastebin.com/ has, where if you control + s it does an action. I've already tried

```
    $(window).keypress((e) => {
    if (!(e.which == 115 && e.ctrlKey) && !(e.which == 19)) return true;
    console.log('bruh');
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

That DOES work, but the save as page still shows up, where as on hastebin, it does not when you do ctrl + S

Any ideas?

Comment: I love the `console.log('bruh')`, I think we've all been there. 

Comment: Thank you hahaha its been uhhh... quite a day i should say hahaha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `keydown` rather than `keypress`:

```js
$(window).on("keydown", (e) => {
    if (e.key === "s" && e.ctrlKey) {
        console.log("Ctrl+S");
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

```html
<div>Click here, then press Ctrl+S</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

In that example I've used the [`key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) property rather than the deprecated `which` property, but if you need to support obsolete browsers you could use `which` (perhaps as a fallback).

Comment: Thank you so much man, what a thing I overlooked 

Comment: It is true the `.which` is deprecated in [plain JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/which). But that is a totally valid [jQuery method](https://api.jquery.com/event.which/).

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette - The fact jQuery polyfills, etc., doesn't make it undeprecated. :-)

Comment: The flip side being: It's not like `which` is going away. :-D

Answer (score 2):

CTRL+S fires keydown event, not keypress event AFAIK.

```
$(window).on("keydown", (e) => {
    if (e.key === "s" && e.ctrlKey) e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Thank you! You and TJ are amazing <3

Comment: Select TJ answer, it has more information :) And I'm glad you found it useful tho!

Comment: Appreciate the kindness! I hope you're having a good day <3